# I've completely screwed up my computer by removing compiz then purging dconf*, is there any way to salvage the situation?

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, restore, dconf

I removed compiz to reinstall it, then I couldn't reset it because dconf couldn't get a connection and nothing else was working, so in my frustration I decided to purge dconf* and reinstall it all, but by doing that I completely wrecked ubuntu.

My desktop is an unresponsive black screen with a mouse, and I'm trying to somehow get out of this using a tty terminal. Nautilus, unity, and pretty much everything else doesn't exist anymore,

I can't use apt-get for anything because I get a whole mess of errors along the lines of:

```
Failed to fetch ..... Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Is there anything I can do to save my documents and maybe restore my operating system to something functional?

Answer (score 0):

To save your data, boot from a live CD/USB and copy the data to a network share, USB drive, or other device.

Comment: I managed to save the data by booting from windows and using Linux reader: http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/, now I'm hoping I can restore the operating system with my software and preferences preserved.